# Set value to dynamically generated dropdown list in a tabular Grid Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

There are many other controls in each row with this particular dropdown list. after a redirection, on ngInit, I have value in **item**, then I am setting the **item**'s value in each row. everythin working fine. But for this dropdown list, just updating the item.duration model is not showing the selected value of the drop down list.

```
                 <td>
                  <select class="form-control" (change)="durationChange(item, $event.target.value)" [value]='item.duration'>
                    <option value="1">1 Month</option>
                    <option value="3">3 Months</option>
                    <option value="6">6 Months</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `ngModel`

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)] ="item.duration" (change)="durationChange(item, $event.target.value)" [value]='item.duration'>
```

Comment: Such a quick accurate answer! Thank you very much :)

Comment: make sure to check this as answer if this helped :D